# HTTP Error 500.37 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start within startup time limit

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

When deploying a new .net 8 project to a windows 2022 server and within IIS, I get this error when trying to launch it:

> HTTP Error 500.37 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start within startup
> time limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause was because I accidentally created this api using the `ASP.NET Core Web API (native AOT)` template that uses `CreateSlimBuilder` in the Program.cs file.  `CreateSlimBuilder` is for AOT and has no support for IIS.  I switched it to the old `CreateBuilder`, built and re-published and now it works.